# Power BI Matrix - Only Show Subtotals for Numeric Values

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Fairly new to Power BI, trying to replicate SSRS reports but am struggling with what in SSRS would be really simple.

I have a matrix which has subtotal rows for the "groups". Some of the values in the matrix are text values rather than numbers. I want to remove the text "subtotals" from the subtotal row, but can only see how to remove the entire row.

For example, I have a value called Deal Type which can hold Growth, Primary or Secondary so in the subtotal row, I am seeing Growth, where I actually don't want to see anything.

We are evaluating Power BI for our business and it seems one day we find something that we love and then next day, a bunch of minus points.

Thanks for your help

EDIT

[image: Test Matrix]

As you will see, for the subtotal and total rows, I don't want to see Primary, France, and EUR but I do want the values of the numeric columns.

Unrealized and CompanyName are used as the Rows, for security reasons can't show the Company Names.

Hope that helps

Comment: [Edit] your question to show the DAX code for your existing measure. It sounds like you simply need a HASONEVALUE function, but it's impossible to be sure without seeing your code.

Comment: The data comes from SQL Server, from a View, so there is no DAX code

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a precise answer without any visibility of your actual data structure... But it sounds like you need to create a `measure`, something like:

```
=IF ( 
    HASONEVALUE ( MyTable[Group Item] ),
    FIRSTNONBLANK ( MyTable[Deal Type], 1 ),
    BLANK ()
)
```

Comment: Hi Olly, thanks for taking the time to answer. I tried your suggestion, just got blank values all the way down. Hopefully the screen snip below will help. You can see where I have Primary, France, EUR in the subtotal and total rows, I want blank but leave the values in the "detail" rows

Comment: Now trying to work out how to insert a screen snip :(